# 'resample' to have the same size of signals

Tags: matlab, size, signals, interpolation, resampling

i have 4 (2 Rates and 2 Times) signals and i need to equalize their sizes. I cut them first off, because i need that too. Size of first time and rate signal is 3901, another 830. But not just to remove elements, i want to keep the curve. I thought i need interpolation and tried "resample" but it is not perfect. Looks like photo. How should i improve my codes? Any idea?

```
 index=time >= 9.6 & tsyn <= 13.5; %time boundaries of first time signal
 time1=tsyn(index); %first time signal
 time_f=resample(time1,830,3901);
 Rate1=CLU_YR1(index)              %first rate signal
 Rate_f=resample(Rate1,830,3901);

 index2 = cm.Time.data >= 26.3 & cm.Time.data <= 30.45; %time boundaries of second time signal
 time2=cm.Time.data(index2)   %second time signal
 Rat2=cm.BodySensor_SC1_Omega_B_z.data*(-180/pi)        %second rate signal
 Rate_p=Rat2(index2)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want both signals to be of length 3901, or 830?

Comment: have a look at [`interp1`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) instead of `resample`. It offers different options (linear, spline, etc...) which can be useful to interpolate your signal when you need to up-sample it.

Comment: Please don’t remove relevant information from your question after you’ve received your answer. If there is confidential information that you accidentally disclosed, contact StackOverflow to permanently remove that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose some of the misfit of your curves originates from the fact that the original sequence is not (close to) 0 at the end of the vector. From the matlab [resample documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html):

> When filtering, resample assumes that the input sequence, x, is zero before and after the samples it is given. Large deviations from zero at the endpoints of x can result in unexpected values for y.

What the best alternative is depends on what it is you want to do next. If you want to have a new, upsampled version (i.e. both signals of length 3901), you could look at [`interp1`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html), which supports several different methods. If you choose to do this, keep in mind that the values in `y(t)` will be interpolated according to the values of `t` you provide. Since your time arrays do not seem to be aligned (one is between 9.6 and 13 sec, the other between 26 and 30), you are probably best off doing something along the lines of:

`y_new = interp1( linspace(1,100,830), rate_p, linspace(1,100,3901), 'linear');`

and the same for the time array.